# EliteBook 8540w suffers BSoD whenever power or monitors are unplugged

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-quadro, hp-elitebook

I have a HP EliteBook 8540w with an Nvidia Quadro FX 1800M video card. Every time I unplug an external monitor or the power, it gets a Blue Screen of Death. Are there some drivers I should update? Is this just a manufacturing defect?

Comment: What does the blue screen say?

Comment: Don't know it's up for about 1 second then the computer restarts.

Comment: To get Windows to not reboot on blue screens so you have time to take a look, go to Control Panel, change "View By" to icons, then go to System -> Advanced System Settings, click on "Settings..." in the Startup and Recovery section, then uncheck the box under "System Failure" that says "Automatically Restart".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reinstall the chipset drivers.
2. Reinstall the graphics driver; if the Nvidia site doesn't give a recent driver, try [Laptop Video 2 Go](http://laptopvideo2go.com).
3. Check your event log for warnings/errors that could you help troubleshoot further.
4. A BSOD usually leaves a dump to check, look for files in `%SYSTEMROOT%\Minidump` or look for a for `MEMORY.DMP` in `%SYSTEMROOT%`. You can compress the file with a progarm like 7-Zip and upload it, or you could use WinDBG from the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) to debug it yourself (in which case you need to open it, click or enter `!analyze -v` and try to make sense of the outpt).

   It would mention the most likely driver that caused the problem; well, if it was a driver...

Comment: Looks like it was driver related.

Answer (score 1):

Try following the steps described in the following blog post:

[Issues with NVIDIA drivers on HP 8540w - The Plexus - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hakoman/issues-with-nvidia-drivers-on-hp-8540w)

> - Before you install the drivers, go to power options and click on “Change plan settings” on any power plan
> - Click on “Change advanced power settings”
> - For each power option (in the dropdown list) disable the “Link State Power Management” options (on battery and plugged in) under PCI
>   Express – make sure you change this for all power options in the
>   dropdown list (balanced, high performance, power saver and any others
>   that are available)
> - Install the latest NVIDIA Drivers
> - After installing the drivers and before rebooting, for each power option disable the “NVIDIA Display Power Saving technology” under
>   Display for both “On battery” and “Plugged in” options – make sure you
>   change this for all power options in the dropdown list   (balanced,
>   high performance, power saver and any others that are available)
> - Reboot and enjoy